# Requiring a project file from an npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, module, config, require

I have an npm module that requires a config file (provided by the user).
Is there a way to tell that module to look for a specific file in the user's directory ?

I want something like this:

#### *In the module*

`const config = require(USER_ROOT_DIRECTORY + '/config.json');`

#### In the user's project

/node_modules (contains the module file)

/src/index.js

/config.json

#### In the index.js file

`const module = require('module'); // will automatically get the config.json file's content`

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path since you know with npm module requires what file simply add the path inside the module file better to add in index.js example-

```
var config = require('./subfolder/config.json')
```